# jquery submit function() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I'm trying to validate my form with the easiest way possible, but somehow is not working and when I click submit button it just reload page without giving the error message on IsRequired class.

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML5**

```
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <div class="field-wrap"><label>First Name</label></div>
    <input class="thevalue" type="text" minlength="3" style="text-transform:uppercase">
    <div class="IsRequired" style="display:none">Fill first name</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="field-wrap"><label>Second Name</label></div>
    <input class="thevalue" type="text" minlength="3" style="text-transform:uppercase">
    <div class="IsRequired" style="display:none">Fill second name</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="field-wrap"><label>email</label></div>
    <input class="thevalue" type="text" style="text-transform:lowercase">
    <div class="IsRequired" style="display:none">Fill email</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="field-wrap"><label>Country</label></div>
    <select name="Country" class="thevalue cs-select" style="display: none;">

    </select>
    <div class="IsRequired" style="display:none">Select country</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    var bool = false;
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("thevalue");
    var el_ = document.getElementsByClassName("IsRequired");

    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if(el[i].value == "" || el[i].value == null) {
        el_[i].style.display = 'block'; // show message error
        bool = true;
      } else if(el[i].value != "" || el[i].value != null) {
        el_[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    if(bool == true) {
      //no submit without reload
    } else if(bool == false) {
      //submit 
    }

    event.preventDefault();

  })
})
```

Comment: simply use required attribute for vaidation

Comment: try to preventDefault () at the beginning. Then on submit, throw a window.location.refresh

Comment: You can try returning `false` after `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @kevinniel I proceed then it didnt work.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Also, I proceed as recommended then the same problem appears

Comment: Why don't you simply use `required` as @Rupal has suggested. Also, I see that validation messages are showing up when I press submit button.

Comment: This code works when I try. Validation messages are shown, no reload occurs.

Comment: Try to debug it. Put `alert` inside your submit handler, to see if it runs at all.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I put required on each input fields as appointed by @Rupal and put e.preventDefault() at the beginning by @kevinniel.

So, I have changed my code to:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('input[required]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
      $('span.form_error').text('A required field was not filled out');
    }
  });
})
```